# Having issues creating proper class for JSON.Net Deserialization of complex object. Receiving {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, deserialization

This is a VB.Net project.  Cannot seem to get the class library correct for deserializing the response string to the classes.
Error we receive when we try to deserialize is:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'blahblah_Framework_Root.blahblah+Tokenscopelist'
> because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {""name"":""value""}) to deserialize correctly.

**Sample response trying to deserialize:**

```json
{
  "data": {
    "expiresAt": "2021-11-27T01:12:05.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2021-11-13T01:12:05.000Z",
    "identityId": 2347335,
    "identity": {
  "id": 2347335,
  "namespace": {
    "id": 7760,
    "nickname": "org:random-parking"
  }
},
"tokenScopeList": [
  {
    "org": {
      "id": 5995,
      "name": "RANDOM Parking",
      "opal": "opal:prod:helium:alpha:5995:org:5995",
      "parentOrg": null,
      "packagePlans": [
        {
          "id": 50,
          "package": {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Additional Users Over 500",
            "packageFeatures": [
              {
                "config": null,
                "id": 147,
                "feature": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Users Included",
                  "code": "users"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "isSelected": true
        },
        {
          "id": 54,
          "package": {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "Elevator I/O Boards",
            "packageFeatures": [
              {
                "config": null,
                "id": 175,
                "feature": {
                  "id": 21,
                  "name": "Elevator I/O Boards",
                  "code": "elevatorIoBoards"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "isSelected": true
        },
        {
          "id": 38,
          "package": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Premium",
            "packageFeatures": [
              {
                "config": {
                  "count": 500
                },
                "id": 91,
                "feature": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Users Included",
                  "code": "users"
                }
              },
              {
                "config": {
                  "count": 1000000
                },
                "id": 92,
                "feature": {
                  "id": 2,
                  "name": "Administrators",
                  "code": "administrators"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "isSelected": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 2502299,
      "opal": "opal:prod:helium:alpha:5995:user:2502299"
    },
    "scope": [
      "o5995-admin:r",
      "o5995-admin:w",
      "o5995-configurations:r",
      "o5995-configurations:w",
      "o5995-dash:r",
      "o5995-dash:w",
      "o5995-videoProviderPlayback:w"
    ]
  },
  {
    "org": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null
    },
    "user": {
      "id": null,
      "opal": null
    },
    "scope": [
      "i2347335:r",
      "i2347335:w"
    ]
  }
],
"token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZGVw"
  },
      "meta": {
        "accessToken": null
      }
    }
```

**Using this class definition**

```
Public Class RootobjectLogin
    Public Property data As DataumLogin
    Public Property meta As Meta
End Class

Public Class DataumLogin
    Public Property expiresAt As Date
    Public Property createdAt As Date
    Public Property identityId As Integer
    Public Property identity As Identity
    Public Property tokenScopeList() As Tokenscopelist
    Public Property token As String
End Class

Public Class Tokenscopelist
    Public Property org As Org
    Public Property user As User
    Public Property scope() As String
End Class

Public Class Packageplan
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property package As Package
    Public Property isSelected As Boolean
End Class

Public Class Package
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property packageFeatures() As New List(Of Packagefeature)
End Class

Public Class Packagefeature
    Public Property config As Config
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property feature As Feature
End Class

Public Class Config
    Public Property count As Integer
End Class

Public Class Feature
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property code As String
End Class

Public Class User
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property opal As String
End Class

Public Class Org
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property opal As String
    Public Property parentOrg As Object
    Public Property packagePlans() As New List(Of Packageplan)
End Class

Public Class Meta
    Public Property accessToken As Accesstoken
End Class
```

**Ideas?**

Comment: Maybe it's because `PackageFeature, PackagePlan` and `TokenScopeList` aren't properly capitalized?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are websites like [jsonutils](https://jsonutils.com/) which can help you to generate the classes from a json file.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the suggestions. It ended up being a combination of things.  The final issue was an integer field returning a null value.   We had to change several class properties to:   
Public Property identityId As Nullable(Of Integer)